# UIKit: call awakeFromNib programmatically?

Tags: ios, uikit, nib, awakefromnib

I saw this code:

```
CoolButton *coolButton = [[CoolButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 60.0f, 25.0f)];
[coolButton awakeFromNib];
// ...
[coolButton release];
```

`CoolButton` subclasses `UIButton`. Is it OK to call `awakeFromNib` programmatically?

What's the best way to do this if I want to do the same things that are done in `-[CoolButton awakeFromNib]` for times that I want to create the object programmatically, instead of from a nib file?

Should I just define a method and call it in `-[CoolButton awakeFromNib]` and `-[CoolButton initWithFrame]`? Or, is there another initialization method I should define that gets called in both cases: whether I create a `CoolButton` programmatically or from a nib file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't a method that gets called both for objects created in code and objects created from a NIB. You should write a separate method that contains the common initialization logic and call it from both `awakeFromNib` and `initWithFrame:`.

Comment: What about `initWithCoder:`? According to the Documentation, that gets called when loading `UIView` subclasses from a nib file. Does `initWithFrame:` call `-initWithCoder:`? If so, then could I just implement `-initWithCoder:`?

Answer (score 2):

Well `awakeFromNib` is called whenever all of the connections between the XIB and NIB are set. I believe `awakeFromNib` is called on an object when it is initialized from a nib file. So if you are creating it programmatically and not with a NIB file, then there's no need to call `awakeFromNib`. Calling `initWithFrame`, on the other hand, sounds like the way to go. In this function you can programmatically create your view, with no need for a nib file. I could be wrong, but I think `initWithFrame` is called regardless of whether your view is being created with a nib or not.

Comment: `initWithFrame:` is called in AppKit on Mac OS, but not in UIKit on iOS, per the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW18